# Why the smarty code working in mozilla firefox doesn't work in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, function, smarty, smarty2

I've following code snippet in smarty:
(I'm using smarty 2.6.8)

```
<button class="btn" onClick="fnAddComment({$feedlist.feed_id},'{$feedlist.item_id}',{$feedlist.parent_feed_id},'{$feedlist.comment_type_id}');return false;">Send</button>
```

The issue I'm facing is in google chrome browser the last parameter i.e. `{$feedlist.comment_type_id}` is going as blank.

I tried by printing alert in the JS function. I come to know that all parameters are receiving in JS function call in both the browsers except the last one(`{$feedlist.comment_type_id}`).

In firefox its value gets printed whereas in google chrome it doesn't, blank alert appears.

I tried to debug and google for the solution bu couldn't get it.

Someone please help me.

Thanks.

If I check the source code in Google chrome it's as follows :

```
<button class="btn" onClick="fnAddComment(7205,'346',0,'');return false;">Send</button>
```

If I check the same source code in Mozilla firefox it's as follows :

```
<button class="btn" onClick="fnAddComment(7205,'346',0,'document');return false;">Send</button>
```

Comment: It would help if you could post the fnAddComment code.  Also, use view source to see what is being delivered to the browser.

Comment: @user2182349 : Please see my updated question. Added the HTML source code received in both the browsers. As the HTML in Chrome itself doesn't contain that last parameter I don't think there is any need to check the JS function.

Comment: How did you check the source code?  View source or inspect element?

Comment: @user2182349 : in both ways

Comment: I doubt that the problem is with browsers, since smarty is serverside.